# Cannot push onto Github repository

Tags: git, github

I am having trouble pushing code from my machine to github. I have setup the repos:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:hugeeee/demo_app.git
```

I get this error when type the command `git push -u origin master`:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Can anybody please direct me towards the solution?

Comment: Does it really say "Could not resolve hostname github: ..."?  Or does it say "Could not resolve hostname github.com: ..."?

Comment: It says could not resolve github. I have followed the instructions laid out on the github website.

Comment: Have you customized your `~/.ssh/config`?  If so, please add the contents of that file to the question.  It would also be helpful if you said what operating system and git version you are using.

Comment: Can you try if `ssh -T git@github.com` works.

Comment: I'm working with Ubuntu 11.10, git 1.7.5.4, I have an id_rsa.pub key already linked with my github. I don't need to generate another key do I? I don't have a config directory in .ssh/

Comment: @Lycha Yes that works. I am welcomed and successfully authenticated.

Comment: did you make first commit ? Did you try without -u ?

Comment: @mkls Yes, there's nothing to commit. And I get the same error message when I push without -u.

Comment: If it says "Could not resolve hostname github: ..." then it's using the hostname "github" instead of the hostname "github.com".  Either your remote repo is defined incorrectly, or your ssh configuration maps "github.com" to "github".  Show us the output of "git remote -v".

Comment: Yes your right @rob mayoff the output is github. How do I change this? Thanks for the help

Comment: This message appear when you are disconnected to the internet as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:hugeeee/demo_app.git
```

Make sure you actually say "github.com".  You probably left out the ".com" when you created the remote.